# Plot R vector with keys as X-axis and values as Y-axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a vector created from a list as such:

```
l1 = list()
l1["a"] = 5.5
l1["b"] = 3.4
l1["c"] = 9.2

v1 = unlist(l1)
v1 = sort(v1, decreasing = F, index.return = T)
```

With this new vector I am trying to plot a line graph so that the 'keys' ("a", "b", "c") are labeled on the x-axis and the 'values' (5.5, 3.4, 9.2) are labeled on the y-axis. So far I have tried the following.

```
plot(v1, col = "red")
line(v1, col = "black")
```

I receive the error

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
Calls: plot -> plot -> plot.default -> xy.coords
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, that is a really roundabout way to create your data. You could have just done: `sort(c(a=5.5,b=3.4,c=9.2),index.return=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
plot(v1$x, type = "l", xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = v1$ix, label = names(v1$x))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works, thank you! I am interested in having dots along my line graph for each x-axis item. How could I add them to this graph?